# Swift. Represent northerly direction as a range of course direction

Tags: swift, mapkit, cllocation

I'm working with annotations and MapKit. I have a bike annotation where the default image points east (ie a side view of a bike which has the concept of up, down, front, and back). If the CLLocation course of the bike is west, I need to use a flipped image (ie image pointing west) otherwise the bike travels backwards. To avoid excessive "flipping" of the annotation image I want to have a buffer zone at due north and due south where, for example, if the bike's course is east (and hence the image used is the east facing bike image), if the course veers a little west (say 184 degrees) then this is considered "within the buffer zone" and I don't use the flipped image on the updated annotation. Say buffer zone is 5 degrees either side of due north and due south. I want to capture these "directions" in variables ie effectiveEast is range 5.0..<175, southBuffer is range 175..<185, effectiveWest is 185..<355 ... but how would I represent the northBuffer .... which effectively needs to be a range from 355 to 360 and also from 0 to 5 ie not contiguous numbers ... I'm guessing this should be quite simple to do mathematically but just can't think of how?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly the flipping happens on the north-south axis. It is useful to have an `enum` for flipping:

```
enum Direction {  //image flipping
   case left, right
}
```

You can use that to keep track of the flipping state

```
var direction: Direction = .right // east
```

The course is a `Double` that runs from 0 to 360 degrees.

```
var course = CLLocation.course
```

The buffer zone is whatever you like

```
var buffer:Double = 5 // 5 degrees each side of north or south
```

You can set the image flipping based on the current state of `direction`.

```
func setImage(_ course: course) {
    switch(direction){
        case .right: // east
          if(course < 360 - buffer || course > 180 + buffer){
             direction = .left
             // flip image to left
          }
        case .left: // west
          if(course > buffer || course < 180 - buffer){
             direction = .right
             // flip image to right
          }
      }
  }
```

Notice that there is a dead zone created by `buffer` for example due north between 355 and 5 degrees where `direction` is whatever was set last. This means as your course moves from east to west the image is flipped west only when you pass the buffer boundary.